# PHP Login With Google Anda Get All Blog From Google Blogger API

Tags: php, api, blogger, google-blogger-api

I'm making an application using blogger api from google.

what I want is when successful login I can display all the blogs that I have on the blog spot,
I have 2 blogs on blogspot `blog-api-test.blogspot.com` and `blog-api-test-2.blogspot.com`

I have successfully logged in with the following code, and in this project I use google-api-php-client and use the service provided,
**so how can I display an option to choose both of my blogs?**

> my simple code

```
<?php

require 'init.php';

if (!$oauth_credentials = getOAuthCredentialsFile()) {
    echo missingOAuth2CredentialsWarning();
    return;
}

$redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig($oauth_credentials);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Blogger::BLOGGER);
$service = new Google_Service_Blogger($client);

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $token = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET['code']);
    $client->setAccessToken($token);

    // store in the session also
    $_SESSION['upload_token'] = $token;

    // redirect back to the example
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

// set the access token as part of the client
if (!empty($_SESSION['upload_token'])) {
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['upload_token']);
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        unset($_SESSION['upload_token']);
    }
} else {
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
}
?>

<div class="box">
<?php if (isset($authUrl)): ?>
    <div class="request">
        <a class='login' href='<?= $authUrl ?>'>Login Now</a>
    </div>
<?php endif ?>
</div>
```

**or from what I want you guys to have a tutorial?**